# DBFIT : Getting Error Couldnt find fixture?

Tags: dbfit

I am new to DBFIT and need help in resolving the issue couldn't find a fixture

by looking at forums in this site I have added import fixture but that didn't help either.

I get an error as 
Could not find fixture: import
Could not find fixture: ConnectUsingFile.
Could not find fixture: dbfit.PostgresTest
Could not find fixture: Query.

Code is as below

```
!contents -R2 -g -p -f -h
!|import fixture|
|dbfit.fixture|


!define redshift_conn_file {pica-dev.dbfit.connection}
!define sds_schema {sds}
!define ins_schema {ins}


!| dbfit.PostgresTest |
!|Connect using file|${redshift_conn_file}|

    enter code here

!|Query|!-

select case when count(*) > 0 then false else true end as test_result from sor.ccr_cc_claim;
-!|
|TEST_RESULT|
|TRUE|
```

Comment: Here is the code                                                                                                                 

!|import fixture|
|dbfit.fixture|


!define redshift_conn_file {pica-dev.dbfit.connection}
!define sds_schema {sds}
!define ins_schema {ins}


!| dbfit.PostgresTest |
!|Connect using file|${redshift_conn_file}|


!|Query|!-

select case when count(*) > 0 then false else true end as test_result from sor.ccr_cc_claim;
-!|
|TEST_RESULT|

Comment: Please put your code and error messages in your questions. Is that the complete error message? Does the error say which fixture was not found?

Comment: have added code and error message now

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `!path lib/*.jar` that brings DbFit in. That have to be the top row in all test pages.

E.g. from [Getting Started](https://dbfit.github.io/dbfit/docs/getting-started.html):

> In order to load the DbFit extension into FitNesse, your test pages have to load the correct libraries. Replace the contents of the big textbox with the following:
>
> `!path lib/*.jar`